# Is editing a question to remove all content okay?

Tags: discussion, editing

[This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22332/creating-my-first-real-game-questions-about-game-design-structure-release) was closed, and in response, the author edited the question to remove all the original content and encourage us to vote for deletion (edit history [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/22332/revisions)). I rolled the edit back because I feel that this kind of behavior is unwarranted and bad for the site.

Even though a question is closed, it remains available so that it can either be salvaged into a good question and reopened, or if nothing else it provides examples of what the community thinks a bad question is so that we can discourage subsequent bad questions and hopefully end up with more, better, questions overall.

Furthermore in this specific example, the edit was allegedly done to "protect the idea" outlined in the initial post, which I feel is an irrelevant reason for obliterating a post (especially since the revision history exists anyhow).

That said, I wanted to solicit thoughts from the rest of the community as to whether or not my rollback was the appropriate course of action? As far as I know this is the first time we've had this kind of situation.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think you did the right thing

Comment: Self-vandalism is looked down upon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94421/how-to-best-handle-the-possible-vandalism-of-own-posts-flag

Comment: I was thinking about rolling back to the previous version as well. I guess I didn't do so because I thought it would upset the OP... that's why I left the "hint" about the revision history. Anyway, I think you did the right thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it absolutely is not acceptable to blank a closed question. It's simply the act of someone who is clearly unfamiliar with how Stack Exchange sites work.

Also of someone who thinks that his "idea" of a networked game about buying and selling stuff is actually worth something. Yeah, never heard that one before...